# PHP included file shows in "get_included_files()"... but class cannot be found

Tags: php, class, oop, include

In my PHP project I have class `User` in Users.class.php then the class `CurrentUser` in CurrentUser.class.php extending `User` class.

I put `include_once('Users.class.php');` at top of the CurrentUser.class.php file then

```
class CurrentUser extends User{...} //this is where the problem points to the error
```

> Fatal error: Class 'User' not found in /home/content/97/12097397/html/diary/source/CurrentUser.class.php on line 5

but `print_r(get_included_files()));` shows the included file. I don't understand why this happens?

(yes my file and class names are not identical, i didn't realize it until I've used it many places. So its hard to reverse it. But it isn't a issue, is it?)

---

PS:
maybe this is where I screwed up.

I use a file named "SessionHandler.php" on the top of almost every php file. In that file i had to include the file "CurrentUser.class.php",  because I'm using CurrentUser class to verify whether user logged-in.

And I have this SessionHandler.php included in Users.class.php

I'm sorry this is a mess.

Comment: Are they in the same namespace?

Comment: what's the contents of users.class.php?  If 'User' isn't found, maybe the class name has a typo in it.

Comment: You include Users.class.php but it is looking for 'User' Class.

Comment: I'm afraid my knowledge about namespaces is less. What did you mean by that?

Comment: @rccoros PHP extends classes based on the class name and not the file name.

Comment: I think @rccoros is merely pointing out a potential typo.

Comment: @shan Open your Users.class.php file. Is you class named `User` or `Users`? If it's the latter (and your file name seems to indicate you do), you have a typo.

Comment: class name is User, and file name is Users.class.php

Comment: Yes that is my intention. I'm thinking that's it's just a typo error.

Comment: There's no need to be defensive. Understand that a LOT of people use [autoloading](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php), where the class name is the same as the file name. So it's an obvious problem to point to. The next potential problem is namespaces. Does either file have a `namespace` declaration?

Comment: @Machavity: no namespace that I've declared

Comment: My issue is why this class is invisible, even when it is showing in the files array

Comment: @shan Can you post the class declaration of `User` in `Users.class.php`?